# Prove that functions $\phi$ that are zero except on some finite subset of $A$ are dense in $\ell^2(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In his book "Real and Complex Analysis", chapter "Elementary Hilbert Space Theory", Walter Rudin introduces the following theorem:

Let $\ell^2(A)=\{\phi: \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\; | \; \sum_{a\in A}| \phi(a)|^2<\infty  \}$ and $D= \{\phi: A\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\; | \; \exists F\subseteq A\; \mbox{finite} \; |\; \forall a \notin F, \phi(a)=0 \}$.

Then $D$ is dense in $\ell^2(A)$. He proves the theorem by referring the reader to a result from another chapter ($L^P$-Spaces).

Is there another way to prove this, without using concepts from $L^P$-Spaces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each finite subset $F \subset A$, define
$$
s_F := \sum_{a\in F} |\varphi(a)|^2
$$
Since $\alpha:= \sum_{a\in A} |\varphi(a)|^2 < \infty$, for any $\epsilon > 0, \exists F_0 \subset A$ finite such that
$$
|s_F - \alpha| < \epsilon^2 \quad\forall F\supset F_0 \text{ finite}
$$
Now define $\psi \in D$ by
$$
\psi(a) = \varphi(a) \text{ if } a\in F_0 \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise}
$$
Then note that
$$
d(\varphi,\psi) < \epsilon
$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I am not sure I see how this proves that $D$ is dense in $\ell^2(A)$: the definition of a dense subset I am familiar with is "$D$ is dense in  $\ell^2(A)$ if the closure of $D$ ($=\overline{D}$) equals $\ell^2(A)$". How does this proof relate to this definition?

Comment: This proof shows that every open ball intersects $D$ non-trivially, which is equivalent to saying that $D$ is dense.

Answer (score 0):

$D$ is a vector space that contains the functions $\phi_a$ defined by $\phi_a(a)=1, \phi_a(x)=0$ for $x\neq a$.  The closed linear span of the latter set is $l^2$.  So the closure of $D$ contains $l^2$ (and $l^2$ contains $D$).

(assuming $A$ is countable.. maybe it still works anyway)

Comment: How does this show that the closure of $D$ contains $\ell^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Since that is a convergent series, all but a countable number of $\phi(a)$ are $0$, also any arrangement of those ones $a_1, \dots, a_n, \dots$ has limit $0$.
So taken a function $\phi$, $\forall \varepsilon >0 $ you can always find a $\psi \in D$ such that $d(\phi,\psi) < \varepsilon$: you just need to take $\psi(a)=0$ if $a \neq a_n$ for all $n$ or if $a=a_s$ and $\sum_{i>s}|\phi(a_i)|^2>\varepsilon$ and $\psi(a)=\phi(a)$ otherwise.

Comment: Oops, I retract my previous comment. Don't know what I was thinking. Since $\sum_{x \in A}|\phi(x)|^2$ is finite and is by definition the supremum of all sums taken over finite subsets of $A$, the set $A_n = \{x \in A : |\phi(x)| > 1/n\}$ is finite for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $\{x \in A : \phi(x) \neq 0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ is countable.

Comment: Hi, do you mean "$\cdots \psi(a) = \phi(a) $ otherwise" in the last line?